# Maven 3 build-extension & IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

I came across the notorius situation of jar-references, which are not available through any public repositories. And I am trying this solution: [by Brett Porter 28/Mar/11 9:00 AM](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3989?focusedCommentId=261657&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-261657)

So I checked out http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/sandbox/trunk/examples/extensions/bundled-repository-extension, built it with IDEA and put resulting **bundled-repository-extension-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** directly into **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4\lib\ext**

Now I am trying to use it like shown [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/sandbox/trunk/examples/MNG-3989-maven3). But IntelliJ IDEA is always highlighting in red that it can't find this build extesnion:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.examples</groupId>
      <artifactId>bundled-repository-extension</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

How can I help it find the build extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension is not found on maven central either. Possible resolutions:

- locate remote repository hosting necessary snapshot and enable it insettings.xml
- install this extension into your local repository manually
- set up your own repository server ( sonatype nexus is good choice ) and upload this extenstion there

One it is available for your maven commandline build IDEA will find it.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I shouldn't have copied the resulting jar anywhere. Just to install it via maven into my default repo did the job.